# Snap.load() svg file IDs removed after Snap.load() function

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

So I load svg file using Snap.load() and one element from that svg file should contain id=eye but when load my svg file there is no id at all. I get the error that i cannot animate property of null. Does somebody know why is this happening and how to fix it?

```
var logo = Snap("#fish");
Snap.load("fish.svg", function(data){
    logo.append(data);
    var eye = logo.select("#eye");
    logo.click(function(){
        eye.animate({transform: "t100,0"}, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Need to see the fish.svg